# Get position side of first line

Tags: location

Tryng get code position side of first code!

```
        $fetchcategory = $results['category'];
        $string = array ( '/\b(.*?)\b/i' );
        $replace = array ( '<a href="?inav=category&amp;category=$1">$1</a>' );
        $category = preg_replace($string, $replace, $fetchcategory);
        echo '<p class="news_cat" /><p class="news_date"><img title="News category!" dir="ltr" src="img/category.png" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" /> Category: '.$category.'</p>';
        echo '</p>';
```

This is code what i want show side to the first one what is

```
        echo '<p class="news_date"><img title="Date added!" dir="ltr" src="img/info_date.png" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" /> ';
        $timestamp = $results['timestamp'];
        $date = strtotime($timestamp);
        echo $postdate = date("d.m.Y",$date);
```

Comment: Sorry, i have a very hard time trying to understand what you want. Can you possibly write some more about what functionality you are after?

Comment: My site: http://filmsground.net/?inav=newsitem&id=7 i want that Category shows next to Date

Comment: Do you want to have both the date and category on same line like this? ![Inline date and category](http://i.imgur.com/KHEL8zH.png)

Comment: yes, that way i want it works!

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your PHP so you echo out both the information for the date and category at the same time. Inside the paragraph with class `news_date`, lets have a look at the code for the category

```
echo    '<p class="news_cat" />'.
        '<p class="news_date">'.
            '<img title="News category!" dir="ltr" src="img/category.png" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />'.
            'Category: '.$category.
        '</p>';
```

And the code for the date

```
$timestamp = $results['timestamp'];
$date = strtotime($timestamp);

echo    '<p class="news_date">'.
            '<img title="Date added!" dir="ltr" src="img/info_date.png" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />';
echo    $postdate = date("d.m.Y",$date);
// Missing end thag for paragraph!
echo    '</p>';
```

if we merge those together we get something like this:

```
$timestamp = $results['timestamp'];
$date = strtotime($timestamp);

echo    '<p class="news_date">'.
            '<img title="Date added!" dir="ltr" src="img/info_date.png" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />';
echo    $postdate = date("d.m.Y",$date);
echo    '<img title="News category!" dir="ltr" src="img/category.png" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />'.
        'Category: '.$category.
        // Missing end tag for paragraph!
        '</p>';
```

And then the output is this:

```
<p class="news_date">
    <img dir="ltr" src="img/info_date.png" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" title="Date added!">
    20.08.2015
    <img class="" dir="ltr" src="img/category.png" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" title="News category!">
    Category:
    <a href="?inav=category&amp;category="></a>
    <a href="?inav=category&amp;category=Film">Film</a>
    <a href="?inav=category&amp;category="></a>
 </p>
```

And on the page you will have it result in looking like this:

[image: Illustration of end result]

instead of this:

[image: Illustration of page without alteration]

As you can see, by simply dividing the php and output into several lines for debugging it becomes much clearer. We even found ourself a paragraph with no ending tag, but fixed it.